# Background pattern image with low opacity covers text

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, text, background

I can't understand why is the background pattern opacity lowers the opacity of the text which is above it (Article Name and Article). How to make text with 0% opacity and background opacity 32%?

This is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">            
        <div class="row">             
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <h1 class="logo margin-section">Article Name</h1>
                    <p>Article</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

And CSS looks like this:

```
.col-sm-3 {
    background-image: url(../images/pattern.png); opacity: 0.32;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
```